# Use tables for filtering without fully merging all the results?

Tags: sql, oracle

Update: Oracle database, all fields indexed.
This is my first post here so I appologize if I do not ask this correctly.

I have 3 tables A,B,C. Two are very large (B,C). I only need the results from A where they fit criteria in B and C.  But the database (Oracle) ends up trying to merge AB and AC and the whole query runs much slower than I would expect.

Practical example:

- A- Customers: Name, CustomerId
- B- Orders: OrderId, CustomerId, OrderType
- B- SupportTickets: TicketId, CustomerId, TicketType

All of the fields above are indexed.

In my database, there may be 1000's of orders for a single OrderType per customer, and there may be 1000's of support tickets for each TicketType per customer.

1. I want to list all the Customers who have a OrderType of 'squirrelcatcher' and a TicketType of 'ragingescapedsquirrel'.
2. I only need a unique list of Customers and I dont need to include any rows from Orders or SupportTickets.

I am using a simple statement:

```
SELECT C.Name 
FROM 
 Customers C,
 JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerId = C.CustomerId,
 JOIN SupportTickets S ON S.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE 
 O.OrderType='squirrelcatcher'
 AND S.TicketType='ragingescapedsquirrel'
GROUP BY 
 C.Name
```

When I run the query, it times out. I dont think it should take that long to execute. I think it is trying to link all the tables or even all the matching records. But I would think that it would only need to find one match for each and then continue on to the next customer. So it should run very quickly.

Any suggestions to improve the performance?

Comment: mySQL? or SQL-Server? or Oracle?

Comment: Please give sample input and output data

Comment: Are support Tickets specific to an order too or just a customer?

Comment: Do you have and indexes on the tables?  If CustomerID is indexed on each of the tables, that would help.

Comment: regarding sample data..  I dont know if it is practical to give sample data. A small sample would not display the slow performance I am receiving.

Comment: Support tickets and Orders are children to the Customers table, no linking fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT C.Name 
  FROM Customers C
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM Orders O 
                WHERE O.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
                      AND O.OrderType='squirrelcatcher')
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM SupportTickets S 
                    WHERE S.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
                          AND S.TicketType='ragingescapedsquirrel')
```

It will likely be faster than an inner join, because the database only needs to find *one* matching record in order for the condition to be satisfied.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need..  I will try it out and report back.